# Cannot print certain superscripts in unicode

Tags: python, unicode

Using this page 
[How to find the unicode of the subscript alphabet?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17908593/how-to-find-the-unicode-of-the-subscript-alphabet)
I can print all superscripts except j,l,r,w,y,s and h.  Unicode clearly has coded for these superscripts but for some reason it will not work in Python. So for the other superscripts I simply write:

```
ua = u"\u1d43"
ub = u"\u1d47"
uc = u"\u1d9c"
ud = u"\u1d48"
ue = u"\u1d49"
uf = u"\u1da0"
ug = u"\u1d4d"
ui = u"\u2071"
uk = u"\u1d4f"
um = u"\u1d50"
un = u"\u207f"
uo = u"\u1d52"
up = u"\u1d56"
ut = u"\u1d57"
uv = u"\u1d5b"
uu = u"\u1d58"
```

But when I do that for the troublesome superscripts I get error message: "SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 0-4: truncated \uXXXX escape"  As usual the error message makes no sense.  Here is the code I use for the superscripts which will not work:

```
uw = u"\u2b7"
uy = u"\u2b8"
uj = u"\u2B2"
ul = u"\u2E1"
ur = u"\u2b3"
us = u"\u2e2"
uh = u"\u2b0"
```

It must have something to do with the fact that all of those superscripts start with 2 and only have 3 digits.  I have also tried rewriting the codes with both uppercase and lowercase letters.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming Python 3, it's supposed to be a [16-bit or 32-bit hex](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/unicode.html#the-string-type) (i.e. 4 or 8 digits) code. Your error message hints at the 4-digit requirement by saying `\uXXXX`:

```
>>> uw = u"\u2b7"
  File "<stdin>", line 1
SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 0-4: truncated \uXXXX escape
```

However, you can encode your Unicode character in two other ways as well (see the documentation linked above):

```
>>> uw = u"\u02b7"
>>> uw = u"\u000002b7"
>>> uw = u"\N{MODIFIER LETTER SMALL W}"
>>>
```

Comment: Great. If it's an agreeable solution, please don't forget to accept the answer. Thanks!