# How to display Greek letters in Axis labels when plotting with Altair and Jupyter?

Tags: python, latex, jupyter, altair

How to write greek letters in Altair? I need to use some symbols for the axis labels. I am using Jupyter notebook

Answer (score 5):

You can display Greek letters in your axis by using the [Greek Unicode](http://kestrel.nmt.edu/~raymond/software/howtos/greekscape.xhtml) of the symbols you want in your axis.

Working example:

```
import altair as alt
from vega_datasets import data
unicode_gamma = '\u03b3'
# for the notebook only (not for JupyterLab) run this command once per session
alt.renderers.enable('notebook')

iris = data.iris()


alt.Chart(iris).mark_point().encode(
    x=alt.X('petalLength', axis=alt.Axis(title=' Alpha Beta Gamma \u03b1 \u03b2 '+ unicode_gamma)),
    y='petalWidth',
    color='species'
)
```

which produces:
[image: plot with x-axis having Greek characters]

Answer (score 2):

Altair doesn't support Latex math like matplotlib because only Unicode characters are supported in Vega.

I encountered the same issue yesterday when I tried to convert my old plots generated using matplotlib to Altair, and the labels/title didn't display properly. The answer above is great, just want to add that, some common superscripts/subscripts also have their unicodes that can be passed into Altair/Vega.

Check this wonderful answer: [How to find the unicode of the subscript alphabet?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17908593/how-to-find-the-unicode-of-the-subscript-alphabet)