# Store exponent in postgres table

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a value to store in my table

> 10<sup>4</sup>

the only exponent that i can store is `²`.

any solution ?!?

Comment: Have you tried just inserting `1000`?   What does your code look like?

Comment: @GordonLinoff I need it to look like ten exponent <sup>3</sup> not `1000`

Comment: Works for me. What is the problem? https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=49d23d6562f5461a1ae88305f7199476

Comment: @S-Man how to change 3 by 4

Comment: i added 10 exponenet 3 and want to add  4 and 5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to use [translate](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/functions-string.html) function to make a mapper table.

`LOG` to get exponent from ten, then use `concat` to get your expect result.

```
SELECT concat(10,translate(LOG(1000)::varchar, '123456789', '¹²³⁴⁵⁶⁷⁸⁹'))
```

[sqlfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=4c9838b32453068713fc5b5cefe78c24)

Comment: You are a boss bro (i will make it as an answer as soon as possible)

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17908593/how-to-find-the-unicode-of-the-subscript-alphabet

Comment: This is a really great one!