# Subscript "z" in python 3.7

Tags: python

Is there anyway to print a subscript z?

It is not in the list of unicode characters, and I don't see another way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

There are some unicode characters. Example:

Aᶻ

From wiki: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_subscripts_and_superscripts

And here: [How to find the unicode of the subscript alphabet?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17908593/how-to-find-the-unicode-of-the-subscript-alphabet)