# Subscript problem for greek letters in python print function

Tags: python, pysimplegui

I am trying to create a GUI for a phyiscs project and I need subscripts of these things.
`H_0`,
`Omega_b`,
`Omega_dm`,
`Omega_\Lambda`
`Omega_r` 
in the form of latex

My code is something like this

```
   import PySimpleGUI as sg

sg.change_look_and_feel('Topanga')      

layout = [
    [sg.Text('Enter the Parameters')],
    [sg.Text("H\N{SUBSCRIPT ZERO}", size=(15, 1)), sg.InputText()],
    [sg.Text("\N{GREEK CAPITAL LETTER OMEGA}\N{LATIN SUBSCRIPT SMALL LETTER B}", size=(15, 1)), sg.InputText()],
    [sg.Text("\N{GREEK CAPITAL LETTER OMEGA}\N{LATIN SUBSCRIPT SMALL LETTER R}", size=(15, 1)), sg.InputText()],
    [sg.Text("\N{GREEK CAPITAL LETTER OMEGA}\N{GREEK SUBSCRIPT SMALL LETTER LAMDA}", size=(15, 1)), sg.InputText()],
    [sg.Text("\N{GREEK CAPITAL LETTER OMEGA}\N{LATIN SUBSCRIPT SMALL LETTER DM}", size=(15, 1)), sg.InputText()],
    [sg.Text("z", size=(15, 1)), sg.InputText()],
    [sg.Submit(), sg.Cancel()]
]

window = sg.Window('Simple data entry window', layout)
event, values = window.read()
window.close()
print(event, values[0], values[1], values[2], values[3], values[4], values[5])
```

The most interesting thing is that it can print letters such as `M` or `R` but it cannot print `B` ?? Or It can print `phi` but it cannot print `lambda` ?

You can try this to see that this combination works.

```
import PySimpleGUI as sg

sg.change_look_and_feel('Topanga')      

layout = [
    [sg.Text('Enter the Parameters')],
    [sg.Text("H\N{SUBSCRIPT ZERO}", size=(15, 1)), sg.InputText()],
    [sg.Text("\N{GREEK CAPITAL LETTER OMEGA}\N{LATIN SUBSCRIPT SMALL LETTER M}", size=(15, 1)), sg.InputText()],
    [sg.Text("\N{GREEK CAPITAL LETTER OMEGA}\N{LATIN SUBSCRIPT SMALL LETTER R}", size=(15, 1)), sg.InputText()],
    [sg.Text("\N{GREEK CAPITAL LETTER OMEGA}\N{GREEK SUBSCRIPT SMALL LETTER PHI}", size=(15, 1)), sg.InputText()],
    [sg.Text("z", size=(15, 1)), sg.InputText()],
    [sg.Submit(), sg.Cancel()]
]

window = sg.Window('Simple data entry window', layout)
event, values = window.read()
window.close()
print(event, values[0], values[1], values[2], values[3], values[4], values[5])
```

Please help,
Thanks

Comment: Why not use the code-point notation instead of using the names?  Have you tried to access the characters using that approach?  Or paste in the character themselves into the string?

Comment: @MikeyB I tried both it does not work. Or I did it in a wrong way. Idk

Comment: They are not part of the Unicode definition from what I've been able to find.

Comment: @MikeyB Yes it seems that way. Then is a there way to insert an image instead of text ?

Comment: It's a limitation of unicode: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17908593/how-to-find-the-unicode-of-the-subscript-alphabet