# Subscript multiple characters in Julia variable name?

Tags: unicode, julia

I can write:

```
x\_m<TAB> = 5
```

to get `x` subscript `m` as a variable name in Julia. What if I want to subscript a word instead of a single character? This

```
x\_max<TAB> = 5
```

doesn't work. However,

```
x\_m<TAB>\_a<TAB>\_x<TAB> = 5
```

does work, it's just very uncomfortable. Is there a better way?

Comment: Unfortunately, not all ASCII characters exist as unicode sub- or super-scripts, so in general this won't work.  Notably missing are superscript `CFQSXYZq` and all subscript capital letters, along with subscript `bcdfgqwyz`.  Don't ask me why the unicode consortium decided `Fₓ` should work but not `Fy` or `Fz`.  Crazy unicode.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_subscripts_and_superscripts#Other_superscript_and_subscript_characters

Comment: @MattB. Maybe they could only chose a limited number of characters, and thus had to drop some deemed less useful, such as subscript y. Anyway, what I want is to put several *of the supported characters* in the subscript.

Comment: `x_max` doesn't seem *that* bad.

Comment: @imaluengo You could say the same of `x\_1<TAB>` ... it's just cooler ;)

Comment: @becko: my understanding is that it was actually a willful refusal to have a complete set lest people begin to use this as a markup mechanism. Which, of course, begs the question of why have any at all?

Comment: @MattB. you should just post your comment as an answer.

Comment: “Which, of course, begs the question [...]” — Latin-1 has some superscript characters, so Pandora's Box had to be opened for Latin-1 compatibility if nothing else.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As I noted in my comment, not all ASCII characters exist as unicode super- or sub-scripts.  In addition, another difficulty in generalizing this tab completion will be determining what `\_phi<TAB>` should mean: is it `ₚₕᵢ` or `ᵩ`?  Finally, I'll note that since these characters are cobbled together from different ranges for different uses they look pretty terrible when used together.

A simple hack to support common words you use would be to add them piecemeal to the `Base.REPLCompletions.latex_symbols` dictionary:

```
Base.REPLCompletions.latex_symbols["\\_max"] = "ₘₐₓ"
Base.REPLCompletions.latex_symbols["\\_min"] = "ₘᵢₙ"
```

You can put these additions in your `.juliarc.jl` file to load them every time on startup. While it may be possible to get a comprehensive solution, it'll take *much* more work.

Comment: I think it's not ambiguous. `ₚₕᵢ` is `\_phi<TAB>`, and `ᵩ` should be  `\_\phi<TAB>`

Comment: Can this sort of definition be part of a script, rather than in a ``.juliarc.jl`` file and run each time, to ensure portability of the code across machines and sharing across users? Thanks.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17909597/565879 It seems not all characters can be used as subscripts. This is a Unicode limitation, not a Julia limitation. See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6613197/utf8-symbols-for-subscript-letters

Answer (score 3):

Since Julia 1.6 this works for subscripts (\_) and superscripts(\^) in the Julia REPL.

x\_maxTAB will print out like this: `xₘₐₓ`.

x\^maxTAB will print out like this: `xᵐᵃˣ`.